# How do I fix my "duplicate column" error?

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I have included the original problem for reference. I'm not sure how to fix the "duplicate column" error. Also, I have to combine the three datasets into one (hence the duplicate issue). I've seen lots of how-to for 2 datasets combining, but am unsure how to do it for 3 so I was just experimenting.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try using "WHERE" just once. Separate the WHERE clause conditions with "AND". Sometimes syntax errors produce misleading error messages.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you are doing `SELECT *` with a join between two tables which likely have one or more columns bearing the same name.  As a result, if both tables have the same `Player` column, SQL doesn't know how to handle the situation.  The fix is to explicitly list out the columns you want to select.  For example, you could refactor your first query to this:

```sql
SELECT s1.Player AS Player1, s2.Player AS Player2
FROM stint_1 s1
INNER JOIN stint_2 s2
    ON s2.Player_ID = s1.Player_ID
```